# How can I measure the performance of my SQL queries?

Tags: java, sql, performance-analysis

I am working on a data visualization software. The software generates queries based on the requested visualizations.

I want to optimize the queries generated, which means that for a given visualization, I want to know if the query I generated is optimal.
Or at least, I want to know if a code change to the query generation engine will not negatively impact the performance (i.e. for a given visualization, the new query performs at least better than the old one).

I am wondering if there are SQL analyzer solutions that could help optimize my queries.

Thanks